# Force fire of an event in RxJS auditTime Observable

Tags: rxjs, observable

I'm using an RxJS auditTime  Observable to save changes in a document (if any) every 10 seconds. 
It works great but sometimes i need to force the event immediately, e.g when user is about to close the document.

E.g some way to "flush" the observable..

What is the most elegant approach for such a scenario?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a single Subject that is the source to the `auditTime` operator then you can merge it to itself like this:

```
subject.auditTime(10 * 1000)
  .merge(subject.filter(val => val === 'close'));
```

Comment: I do not completely understand. Can you elaborate a bit more? When exactly show I merge? What should i do with the merged Observable?

Comment: You just subscribe after `merge()`

Comment: but how would that be different than just subscribing to subject? I would always get all the event with no time window...

Comment: You can filter them and pass only whatever you want `.merge(subject.filter(val => val === 'close'))`